# Changes in editable template policies is not reflected in existing pages

Tags: aem

I added a new component to my editable template by source code, editing

ui.content\src\main\content\jcr_root\conf\my-site\settings\wcm\templates\my-template\structure.content.xml

and

ui.content\src\main\content\jcr_root\conf\my-site\settings\wcm\templates\my-template\policies.content.xml

I added an embed component.

And it's being added to all the pages.

However, in new created pages the component shows a list of embeddables whereas in already existing pages it does not.

In new pages:

[image]

In already existing pages:

[image]

I know embeddable options are controlled by policies, which are working because the radio button is restricted to "Embeddable / None" via policy (there are more values). I checked both pages using this template.

What could be the cause for this?

We use AEM as a Cloud Service.

Comment: Can you reproduce locally? I would say that simply old pages do not have the initial content of the new pages, since the template has been modified and you will need to either programmatically add/update the proper nodes for the old pages or manually recreate the content.

Comment: We added them programmatically on deployment using Groovy scripts executed via AEM Easy Content Upgrade tool (https://github.com/valtech/aem-easy-content-upgrade). That solved the problem. However, I still don't understand why those nodes weren't added automaticallly as I was editing the structure file of the template.